# Time-Defined IF Statement Executed in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, time, excel-formula

I have a formula that I've been trying to setup to read a data value from the 4th row of a column IF the current time is less than a certain value, ELSE pull from the 2nd row of the column.

```
=IF($Z$16<5,'SOME TEXT'!N4,'SOME TEXT'!N2)
```

Formula for Current Time (Hour) in Cell $Z$16:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"H")
```

The purpose of this IF statement is to account for using old temperature data until 5am, when the new data comes in. I thought that I had this formula set up but, for the past few mornings, it has not worked.

Comment: Are you doing anything to recalculate the formula? They will only recalculate when something else in the sheet triggers this to happen (such as another formula being used)

Comment: Hi Trum. I'm not trying to recalculate anything actually. Just trying to display certain values depending on whether or not the current hour is less than 5am.

Comment: Hi Aaron, That's what I mean - the IF and the Hour won't change until there is a calculation - and so you'll end up with no change until afterwords. So you would have to press F9 to do this manually or use a Macro to do an intermittent update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924542/excel-recalculating-every-x-seconds

This post might be very useful if you want to go down the macro route.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=IF(<time-of-the-day><TIME(5,0,0),'SOME TEXT'!N4,'SOME TEXT'!N2)
```

You would replace `<time-of-the-day>` by any of

```
(NOW()-TODAY())
(NOW()-INT(NOW()))
TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))
TIMEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"H:M:S"))
```

There might be better options to isolate the current time of the day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sancho. Will try using this formula.