# Excel Code Blocking other Excel Sheets from opening

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel file blocks other Excels files from opening.

I have the below code

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "CommonWorkBook.prepareSheets"
End Sub
```

In PrepareSheets Macro, I take data from a txt file every 60 seconds.

The code is as follows

```
Do While 1 = 1
    ' Do Something
    pause 60
 Loop
```

After opening my .xlsm file, I am unable to open other .xlsm files.

If I close my .xlsm file, other files gets opened.

Comment: What is the code for `pause`?

Comment: Rather than fixing your (currently) incomplete code you might want to look at the following working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924542/excel-recalculating-every-x-seconds

Comment: Public Function pause(Optional iSeconds As Integer = 20)
    Dim dtEnd As Date
    dtEnd = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, iSeconds)
    Do While dtEnd > Now: DoEvents: Loop
End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when `Pause` is running it is still *running*. If you look in the task manager while `pause 60` is being executed then you will see that it is using up almost all CPU from one of your cores:

[image]

Even if you *could* fix it -- do you really want to hog so much of your system's resources?

VBA is old technology -- only minor changes since the late 1990s. It is single-threaded. Only one single-threaded instance of the interpreter for each instance of the Excel application. The running code is what is preventing another macro-enabled workbook from opening.

There really is no easy way to do multithreading in Excel (but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5721564/4996248) question). You should look instead for a solution involving `Application.OnTime`. Don't *pause* for 60 seconds -- *schedule* for 60 seconds in the future. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924542/4996248) (as suggested by @Ralph) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to implement the same