# Excel - How to Manualy calculate a worksheet every second?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My sheet contains links from a third application and it's set to Automatic calculation.
New data retrieved every few seconds so I should get the data every second or close to it (One of the fields the sheet retrieved is "time" so I can know how updated is that data).

Yet, I found that the data is updated every 3 minutes (and more..) rather than every second or few seconds.
I changed the Automatic calculation to Manual calculation, Results: Every click on the Calculate Now results with a "new updated" data which is indeed updated from a few seconds ago rather than 3 minutes, like it should be in the first place.

I suppose that the Automatic calculation has an algorithm to decide when to calculate and that algorithm doesn't go into my favor,
So how can I set the sheet calculation to be immediate or at least to be every second or so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924542/excel-recalculating-every-x-seconds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: Recalculating every x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924542/excel-recalculating-every-x-seconds)

Comment: @urdearboy Yes I have tried that. Just tested that for the past few hours to make sure the results are the same. And the results are pretty much the same, the DDE links updated in a lag even with this code. Since I'm using it to get the data of Stock exchange I need it as soon as the data available with few seconds max, 2-3 minutes is too much... :(

Comment: Web scraping takes time. There’s not much we can do about that